# how to compile static linked application using android cross compilation toolchain?

Tags: android, bash, gcc, android-ndk, native

I am trying to compile fbgrab [fbgrab website](http://hem.bredband.net/gmogmo/fbgrab/) for arm devices.

I managed to build it using this command

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/ -lz  -lm  -I../zlib -I../lpng  -W -Wall   -o fbgrab fbgrab.c ../zlib/libz.a ../lpng/libpng.a
```

but it is dynamicly linked and i dont now how to install shared libraries on device

```
localhost:fbgrab-1.0 anatoly$ file fbgrab
fbgrab: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

So i need to build it with static linked libraries
when i try to use -static option compilation fails with this message `ld: cannot find -lz` although shared libraries are located in pointed directories

what is the problem here? how to build static linked binary? or how am i able to install shared libraries on to device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily install shared libraries, by either including their sources in your project and building them using the NDK tools, or by including a prebuilt shared lib.  One can also use the NDK to do static linking as well.  Have a look at these docs in your NDK directory:
**/android-ndk-r7/docs/PREBUILTS.html**
**/android-ndk-r7/docs/ANDROID-MK.html**

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for answering. Finally i managed to build what i wanted, but discovered that there is no way to build fully static library, cause some libraries are dynamicly linked only (libc libm if i am not mistaken)